# WooCommerce - Open the new product that the category is selected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I've been searching all over the internet for hours how to automatically assign a category to new products. When you open the new product that the category is selected.

I have two product categories (Books and FIlms) and I would like that every time we open a new product, Books are selected. In this way it will directly show the custom fields of that product category and we will speed up the creation process.

It's possible?
thanks

---

**UPDATE**

I found a code that seems to work with the posts. Any idea how I can adapt the code for products and where should I put the category I care about?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243462/automatically-select-categories-on-new-post-based-on-get-value

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to the checkbox that should already be checked when creating a new product, you can use jQuery

Replace `in-product_cat-15` with `in-product_cat-{YOUR-CAT-ID}`

```php
// Define the admin_head callback 
function action_admin_head() {
    global $post, $pagenow;

    // Only on new product pages    
    if( $pagenow != 'post-new.php' ) return;
    ?>
    <script>    
    jQuery(function($){
        $( '#in-product_cat-15' ).attr( 'checked', true );
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'action_admin_head', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Wow! correctly selects the desired category when creating a new product but custom fields created with ACF are not displayed. I need to deselect and re-select the category for them to appear. Some idea?

Comment: voted because for understanding OP's question clearly and the answer is elegant too.

Comment: @EnricSerraDuran I am not using ACF, so I cannot see or test this in detail. What you could try is replacing `admin_head` with `admin_footer`. Although I do not immediately know whether this will make a big difference. 
You should see what action is triggered by ACF, 
it seems logical to me that this is done with jQuery

Comment: I see that admin_footer does not activate ACF either. :(
One question, it only affects the admin user? because the seller users see that the automatic selection does not work for me.

Comment: I found a code that seems to work with the posts. Any idea how I can adapt the code for products and where should I put the category I care about?

thanks

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243462/automatically-select-categories-on-new-post-based-on-get-value

Answer (score 1):

In product categories click the `Make default` action of your desired category to make it as default category. For more details refer the image:

[image: Product Category]

You can visit this page using this URL (replace the domain with your domain):
`www.example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't work as expected.